# Does Java Compiler / VM optimize temp variables which are for inspecting in debugger

Tags: java, variables, optimization, temporary, inlining

Here are two versions of the same method.

```
public static int getSomeValue() {
return getValueX() * getValueY() - getValueZ();
}
```

```
public static int getSomeValue() {
int jX = getValueX();
int jY = getValueY();
int jZ = getValueZ();
int jRet = jX * jY - jZ;
return jRet;
}
```

The second method is great for debugging, one can put a break point on say "return jRet" and inspect the three values.

Will the Compiler / JVM optimize these variables out?

Comment: That's very implementation-dependent. **On my compiler**, it does, but you shouldn't worry about these micro-optimisations anyway. Even if the compiler doesn't optimise it away, the jitter probably will, and you probably have better things to optimise than this.

Comment: So as I understand the JITter would (may / should ) remove there. So then is there an option for the java compiler to optimize like we have for the -O2 for C compilers. This example has primitive entities, so the compiler will allocate on the stack, but if these were three objects, say Strings, it would do the same for object references, but will have the overhead of ref-incr/ref-decr... What do you gurus think?